# How to use MarkLogic search options by name

Tags: search, marklogic

I'm using the ML9 Java API to upload a search options file to the DB with a name that I can use later in my search call. I would now like to write an xquery transform to highlight the query-matches in a set of elements in the response. Standard snippets won't work for me since they only bring back the fields in which there are matches and because they may not bring back the complete field value, but only the immediate context of the match.

So I want to use the cts:highlight function in a custom transform and want to pass to it the name of the options that I have uploaded into the DB. My question is how I can best get the options element from the DB using the name passed in to the transform method. I want to use this to construct the cts:query that I can pass in to the cts:highlight call as  in:

```
let $query := cts:query(search:parse($query-string, $options))
let $result := cts:highlight($doc, $query, <markup>{$cts:text}
 </markup>)
```

I was thinking I could pass in the query-string and the name of the pre-loaded options and use these to construct the cts:query, but don't know how to get the options from the name.

Comment: Have you looked at extract-document-data instead? It might be less work and code to maintain for you.  http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_90087

Comment: I have, but how do I highlight search matches in the extracted fields?

Comment: I can't seem to find a single example of how an xquery transform is written. The example code also only shows how to do an XSLT transform.

Comment: There are XQuery, JavaScript, and XSLT transform examples here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms#chapter.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to avoid having to read the options. Setting the option 'return-query' to true adds a search:query node to the search:response which is passed to the transform method as the document-node. I'm then able to get this directly in the transform method to use in cts:highlight as:
       let $query := cts:query($response/search:response/search:query/*[1])

Answer (score 0):

The options are stored in the modules database associated with your REST instance. You could theoretically dig them out, though that would be relying on an implementation detail (the URI).

You might look into a combination of extract-document-data, as Sam mentioned, plus a search result transform, rather than the heavier approach of doing your own search through what I'd guess is a read transform.

Another alternative might be a custom snippeter that you pull into your options via transform-results. See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_58295.

Comment: What I am trying to do is a search results transform that combines extract-document-data and snippettng. Snippeting only brings back the fields that have matches and extracts don't highlight. I'm not sure how I can do what I want without using cts:highlight on the matched document using the cts:query and options that I used to get the results.

Comment: Also I got a URL not found on the link you mentioned.

Comment: Here is the correct link: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_58295 . A custom snippeter might be more efficient than extracting the query and transforming the documents.